# What does 1.f mean

Tags: java, floating-point

While going through a class I saw `1.f` assigned as a value to a float variable. What is the use of the `.` here? How is this different from just `1f`?

Comment: 1.f this means: 1.0f

Comment: Your conjecture that 1.f == 1f == 1.0f is right ofcourse. One could in fact assign 1 (int) to the float variable. So it is a bit of explicitness, that would be better served with a clear `1.0f` (a double with a funny f == float).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's exactly the same as `1f` and means the number `1.0` expressed as a `float` literal. Other ways to express the same literal include `1.0f`, `+1.00000f`, `1e0f`, `1.e+0f` and so on.

For a detailed specification, see [§3.10.2. Floating-Point Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) in the JLS.

Answer (score 1):

It's not different at all.

1.f is the same as 1.0f or 1.00000000f or 1f.

Answer (score 1):

You can express a float literal as '1.'(excluding the quotes). This will mean exactly the same as 1.0. So, here 1.f means actually 1.0f.

Comment: How is this adding anything to the previous answers?